# When we configure log shipping do we have to open a firewall from the destination server to the source server too?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

When we configure log shipping do we have to open a firewall from the destination server to the source server too?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether or not the two instances of SQL Server taking part in the log shipped configuration are:

- On the same server (Then No)
- Behind different firewalls within the same domain/network (Then Yes)

Answer (score 0):

Log shipping contains four separate job by Sql server Agent.
1.Getting back up in primary server
2.Shipping logs to secondary server
3.Restoring logs in secondary server
4.Monitoring the log shipping process (Optional)

in steps 2 and 3, you need have a shared folder in network if your primary and secondary servers are separate and for this you should give access to secondary server to copy all files from primary server.and The important thing is "databases in a log shipping configuration must use the full recovery model or bulk-logged recovery model".

You must be a sysadmin on each server instance to enable log shipping. The backup and restore directories in your log shipping configuration must follow these requirements.

For the backup job, read/write permissions to the backup directory are required on the following:

The SQL Server service account on the primary server instance.

The proxy account of the backup job. By default, this is the SQL Server Agent account on the primary server instance.

For the copy job, read permissions to the backup directory and write permissions to the copy directory are required by the proxy account of the copy job. By default, this is the SQL Server Agent account on the secondary server instance.

For the restore job, read/write permission to the copy directory are required by the following:

The SQL Server service account on the secondary server instance.

The proxy account of the restore job. By default, this is the SQL Server Agent account on the secondary server instance.